# How can I use Dockerfile --from across files

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im trying to split my single Dockerfile into single files that will sit in each repository.

My current file structure is as shown below.

```
V mainui
    ...
    Dockerfile
> linksui
> static
```

currently ive got a single Dockerfile with the contents

*mainui/Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:19-alpine as mainsite

WORKDIR /mainui

COPY /mainui/package*.json /mainui/

RUN npm install

COPY /mainui /mainui/

COPY /static /static

RUN npm run build

FROM node:19-alpine as linkssite

WORKDIR /linksui

COPY /linksui/package*.json /linksui/

RUN npm install

COPY /linksui /linksui/

RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
# move over site content
COPY --from=mainsite /mainui/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=linkssite /linksui/out/ /usr/share/nginx/links

# copy over static files to static folder
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/static
COPY /static/ /usr/share/nginx/static

# move over nginx config files
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx/sites/ /etc/nginx/sites
EXPOSE 80
```

is there a similar syntax to NGINX's `include example.conf` for Docker or is there a better practice for this.

Ive tried separating the 2 node images into their own files but due to the nginx image depending on them both ive not been able to get this working without having 2 nginx images.